# Core Data ID Between two entities

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I currently have two entities in my database:

```
Subjects
Timetable
```

In my `Timetable` entity I have an attribute called

```
subject
```

which needs have some relation to an object in the `Subjects` entity. How would I do this? I can not make this a relationship as for every subject object there could be many timetable objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate entity for the "object" in the Subjects entity.  Let's call it Foo.

Now, Subjects would have a to-one relationship to a Foo.

Inside your Timetable entity, you would then have a to-many relationship to Foo.